# Is my Firebase Database structure correct and efficient? How to add another collection which deals with dynamic calendar?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, nosql

Developing an ecom type app but its based on a single product. Ex : Private labelled One Product sweet. (the whole application sells only one product).

For this, i decided to use firebase for auth and database. So, the i structured database as followed:

```
Firebase databse Structure:
#Users
 -user1
    -profile
 -user2
    -profile

#Orders
 -user1
   -a12as34
      -Order Details
      -Order Details
 -user2
   -29sjasjp
       -Order Detils 

#address
 -user1
    -address
       -address1
       -address2
 -user2
    -address
```

Is the structure effective? Or any better suggestion?

i am planning to use calendar for few task. when ever a product is ordered, delivery person will mark as delivered from mobile app given to them, so dynamically i need to mark the dates which is been marked as delivered.

How to form structure for this? As each user can have multiple orders. is it good to create a structure like this?

```
#OrderDate
   -user1
      -order1
         -marked data1,
         -marked data2,
         -marked data3
```

So that i can use this order1 array to plot in calendar. is there any other structure i can use?

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st structure looks more promising to me but you may change it slightly to make it more efficient as explained below

## users

- user1 details (you can include address array here as its part of the user details only)

`_id: "jsch524xdh",
name:"NAME",
phoneNo:"90010XXXXX",
city: "CITY",
address: [address1 , address2]
other details: "ANY OTHER DATA"`

## orders

1. order details may have keys like  `order_id`, `order_desc`, etc & you must include **`user_id`**. In this way it will be easier to retrieve all orders with just `user_id` from order collection

`_id: "3rtggf4xdh",
order_desc:"DESC",
user_id:"jsch524xdh (of above user)",
other details: "ANY OTHER DATA",
order_date: "1-1-2019",
is_delivered: true`,
delivery_date: "29-1-2019"

## address

I won't suggest to make address collection separate but you can make it in similar fashion

- address :

  `_id : "6723ghcjhchjs",
      desc: "ANY ADDRESS",
      user_id: "jsch524xdh (of above user)"`

For delivery whenever user mark order as delivered just update the order with `is_delivered` true along with date of delivery. Initially values will be false and null(for delivery_date) when you are inserting values of new orders.

I wish you good luck and hope you will achieve your goal as you get the gist :)

You may read official detailed best practice guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Appreciate your prompt reply. Will  look into the structure as you suggested. What about calendar ? Any suggestion for that ?

Comment: I have an doubt, while creating a record i am using .push to get uid for every push. If i need to add the same uid as reference in another collection for example, when new order i would get a uid under a user. How to use the same uid to another collection called calendar for example ? How to retrieve the uid from the orders structure and save data under same uid to the calendar collection. ?

Comment: first push of order will give your order's uid (store in in variable say `o_id`). Now in order to save order details in calendar collections simply pass the  `o_id` whenever you are pushing in calendar collection